# Cryptic, then Crossword, then Clues

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

Answer is one word.

> ### {1}{2}{3}{4} (6)
>
> **{1} [a] (7)
>
>   {2} [b][c][d][e] (6)
>
>   {3} [f] (3)
>
>   {4} [g][h][i] (6)**
>
> [a] Bonding family in cod (7)
>   [b] Container fight (3)
>   [c] Considering primarily ferocity of rhinoceros (3)
>   [d] I lie in a turf (on the back) of crop (5)
>   [e] Just until first ice turns into liquid (5)
>   [f] Man reads P loosely as symbol (9)
>   [g] Massive regal entanglement (5)
>   [h] Gloss with a heart transforms into transparent  material (5)
>   [i] Flask of courage (6)

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First:

> [a] LINKING
>  [b] BOX
>  [c] FOR
>  [d] FRUIT
>  [e] JUICE
>  [f] AMPERSAND
>  [g] LARGE
>  [h] GLASS
>  [i] BOTTLE

Then:

> {1} BETWEEN?
>  {2} CARTON
>  {3} AND
>  {4} CARBOY?

Leading to ...

> many many possibilities, which I suspect we can't resolve before we get to the metapuzzle. ... Having now done some more of the puzzles, I think it's pretty clear that "between" here is in the word-ladder sense and our answer is CARBON.

Comment: aha, you've nailed it **again***... check here!