# Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D

Tags: cipher, metapuzzles

### Introduction

As requested by @Rubio, I am here to state that this is a metapuzzle based on other puzzles listed below.

"[Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150)" ~ Mr Pie

### The Puzzle

Or does it? Answer is a two-digit number.

```
|....-..|||-||...-...||//.||||/....|-.....
```

### Answers from various users in different questions:

1) [Cryptic, then Crossword, then Clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85606/cryptic-then-crossword-then-clues)

> CARBON (by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150))

2) [Word Web - A Hard One](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85607/word-web-a-hard-one)

> CALCIUM (by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150))

3) [Not Just Black and White](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85608/not-just-black-and-white)

> VANADIUM (by [phenomist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37878/phenomist))

4) [Omni-Riley-Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85609/omni-riley-rebuses)

> GERMANIUM (by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150), still...)

5) [Snakes and Ladders](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85610/snakes-and-ladders)

> LEAD (by [JS1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4479/js1))

6) [Nono-Cube: Approach at Your Own Risk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85611/nono-cube-approach-at-your-own-risk)

> RADIUM (by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150), again!!)

7) [Mono-Tonic Crpytic-Clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85612/mono-tonic-crpytic-clues)

> DUBNIUM (by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150/recycling-old-answers#comment236929_81150), for the $n^{th}$ time...)

**The [metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) part is yet to be solved...**

### Hint:

<sub>helpfulness level 1:</sub>

> `|. rot 90°`

Comment: It's showtime ;)

Comment: Wow, so many! You should be the answer in one of the 'I make billions' riddles!

Comment: Is the ellipsis supposed to be a single character, or three separate dots?

Comment: @Deusovi 3 separate dots, will edit, thanks!

Comment: Bofreingvbaf: ngbzvp ahzoref bs ryrzragf yvfgrq ner: 6, 20, 23, 32, 82, 88, 105 naq gurl jrer nyernql fbegrq sebz fznyyrfg gb uvturfg.  Guvf znxrf zr oryvrir gung gur ahzoref ner hfrshy (nf bccbfrq gb gur purzvpny flzobyf P, PN, I, rgp).  V pbhagrq 42 flzobyf va gur pbqr, fb gung pbeercbaqf gb 6 flzobyf cre ryrzrag.

Comment: is this a language ^^^^^(above comment) as google cant decode it?

Comment: @ACoolGuy it is rot13 :) (decode it with rot13.com)

Comment: @Omega Krypton Are they all related to elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As JProblems found out, the cipher is Morse code but with `|` instead of `-`. In decimal form, it's `6-2-7-3//1/4-5`.
>
>  Using the answer from each subpuzzle (e.g. the sixth answer is **radium**, so substitute 6 → radium), we get:
>  
>  `radium-calcium-dubnium-vanadium//carbon/germanium-lead`.
>
>  This describes lines drawn on the periodic table:
>
>  [image]

So the final two-digit answer is

> the atomic number of **Ni** (nickel), which is **28**.

Comment: Ah clever! I wrote down the elements but didn't think to draw the lines on the table. Well done!

Comment: nice job as usual @jafe, will award check later!

Comment: [Perfect!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Comment: Oooooh, it all makes sense now! (Pun intended) +1

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> 61?

Because

> If you rotate the vertical lines 90 degrees, they become dashes. Taking the dots and vertical lines to be Morse code, the small dashes to be minus signs, the single slash to be division, and the double slash to be a "word break" denoting the two separate digits, we have for the first digit 6-2-7-3 = -6, and (admittedly playing fast and loose with the order of operations to get a single digit answer) 1/(4-5) = -1 for the second digit.

In keeping with the other puzzles,

> Element 61 is Promethium, Pm. Perhaps since there are negatives, it is subtracted somehow from the set of other elements to solve the metapuzzle?